# Jira - JQL report to show average number of resolved/created tickets over 30days

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to figure out how to create a JQL query that will pull back the average number of resolved tickets over the last 30 days and the average number of created tickets over the last 30 days...

I've used the created resolved report in Jira which is great, but now I just need the averages calculated..

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that this cannot be achieved using the [out-of-the-box JQL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching).

You can do this easily using Jira's [remote API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference), using [jira-python](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for example :

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('admin', 'admin'))    # a username/password tuple
props = jira.application_properties()
# Find all issues from the last month:
issuesResolved = jira.search_issues('resolved > startOfMonth()')
issuesCreated  = jira.search_issues('created > startOfMonth()')
# and so on...
```

What should the output be exactly? average per day for the last 30 days? average for every 30 months?

Anyway, if you need help coding that let me know... good luck !